Unable to get GitHub Webhook to work with Jenkins
I'm trying to get the GitHub webhook from my private repository to instigate Jenkins jobs build.
As my Jenkins server is an internal network I need to rely on a web relay, I'm currently using Smee.
It seems that the message is correctly got by Smee which then correctly forwards to my Jenkins server, the problem is that Jenkins always throws an exception when trying to identify the GIT repository.
I've got these information out of a log recorder I've enabled in Jenkins, here is the exception I find in the log:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.getUrl()" because the return value of "org.kohsuke.github.GHEventPayload$Push.getRepository()" is null
    at PluginClassLoader for github//org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber.onEvent(DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber.java:76)
    at PluginClassLoader for github//org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.extension.GHEventsSubscriber$4.applyNullSafe(GHEventsSubscriber.java:241)
    at PluginClassLoader for github//org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.extension.GHEventsSubscriber$4.applyNullSafe(GHEventsSubscriber.java:237)
    at PluginClassLoader for github//org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.util.misc.NullSafeFunction.apply(NullSafeFunction.java:18)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.transform(Iterators.java:829)
...

Has anyone have an idea on how I can get past this exception?
Thank you for your attention.

I've finally found something that seemed to solve the issue.
In GitHub project webhook settings I've changed the content type to application /json and everything seems to work now.
